# How could I make a rocket exhaust with a smoke / fire simulation?

Tags: node-editor

How would I be able to make an accurate rocket engine exhaust effect in blender? I hav the model done, but I would like to make this effect better.. Here's my model [image: my model:]

and here's some examples of the effect I want...
[image]

Comment: More density, hires and a larger volume. All add up to more memory for the sim cache

Comment: Could you maybe upload a .blend file (I created a handy [service for that](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) ). As it stands, we don't know what settings you are currently using, and there are a lot of things someone who wishes to answer would need to replicate, which drastically increases the amount of time required to write an answer, making your chances lower.